# Two CUDA folders under /usr/local. Which one should I export?

Tags: cuda, cudnn

I'm sorry if I'm asking a silly question. I'm new to CUDA. Installed CUDA 10.1 using Runfile method and did the following export according to Nvidia instructions:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin
```

Then I try to add cuDNN libraries. However I found two CUDA folders under `/use/local`:

```
cuda
cuda-10.1
```

I run `nvcc -V` in both folders and they are both version 10.1. So now I have two questions:

1. Should I copy cuDNN libraries to `cuda/include` or `cuda-10.1/include` or both?
2. Why did I get two folders? Seems they contain the exact same files. Should I remove one of them to make things clean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am quite sure /usr/local/cuda is a symbolic link to /usr/local/cuda-10.1. You can check this by doing a ls -l /usr/local/cuda

Copying files to include folders in cuda/include or cuda-10.1/include should be one and the same thing.

Comment: Thank for your kind explanation! You're totally right that `cuda` is the symbolic link of `cuda-10.1`. Should have done a throughout check before asking.

Comment: While both are same, which of the 2 is to be used preferably? Are there any considerations to be made?